# Change the value of the object's variable using decorator pattern in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

I have this program that uses Builder Pattern to build an ID Object. I am not sure if the implementation of Builder Pattern is correct. But, this program can create an ID Object. Once the Object is created, I would like to implement Decorator Pattern to add functionalities to my object.

Here is my ID class,

```
public class ID implements IID {
    int width;
    int height;
    String name;
    String idnumber;
    boolean border = false;
    String borderColor;

    public int getWidth() {return this.width;}
    public int getHeight() {return this.height;}
    public String getName() {return this.name;}
    public String getIDNumber() {return this.idnumber;}
    public boolean isBordered() {return border;}
    public String getBorderColor() {return borderColor;}
    @Override
    public void addBorder() {
        this.border = true;
    }
}
```

The `boolean border`, `String borderColor`, `isBordered()`, `getBorderColor()` and `addBorder()` is for Decorator Pattern.

Here is the Interface `IID`,

```
public interface IID {
    void addBorder();
}
```

Here is the Decorator,

```
public abstract class IDDecorator implements IID {
    protected ID decoratedID;
    public IDDecorator(ID decoratedID) {
        this.decoratedID = decoratedID;
    }
    public void addBorder() {
        decoratedID.addBorder();
    } 
}
```

Here is the Concrete Decorator,

```
public class GrayIDDecorator extends IDDecorator {
    public GrayIDDecorator(ID decoratedID) {
        super(decoratedID);
    }
    @Override
    public void addBorder() {
        decoratedID.addBorder();
        setGrayBorder(decoratedID);
    }
    private void setGrayBorder(ID decoratedID) {
        decoratedID.borderColor="Gray";
    }
}
```

I also like to know what is the use of `super()` in this concrete decorator. What is `super()`?

Here is the main class,

```
...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
   IDBuilderDirector idd = new IDBuilderDirector();
    ...
   ID id = idd.construct(roleD, idnumber, fname, lname);
    ...
   IID grayID = new GrayIDDecorator(id);
   id.addBorder();
   if (id.isBordered()) {
       System.out.println("Border: "+id.getBorderColor());
   } else {
       System.out.println("Border: None");
   }
}
```

The `IDBuilderDirector` and related methods is for Builder Pattern.

In the main class, I used `GrayIDDecorator`. After the execution of the program, I have now the ID with border. But why I can't change the value of `borderColor` of the ID? If I call `id.getBorderColor()`, it will return `null`.

Also, I would like to know if implementation of Decorator pattern here in my program is correct.

This is the link that I am following regarding to Decorator Pattern.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern.htm

Comment: `super(...)` is calling the super class' constructor.

Comment: There is no builder pattern there

Comment: Your tutorial implements it a little wrong. See [this](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) and the example it has [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator/java/3) - The point of the abstract decorator is to hide the wrapped item from it's subclasses so they can call `super` like in a regular class hierarchy. If you don't use that, skip the the abstract one entirely.  And you have to use `grayID.addBorder()` in the end. The decorated object replaces the undecorated one. It's a bit like a builder

Comment: @john, yes i didnt include the builder pattern in that codes..